# How to use ipinfo.io in Node.js and Express (and Heroku) application properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, ip

I want to block users from some specific countries, and found that ipinfo.io serves the purpose. But when I tried to use it in my Node.js and Express application, it looks like it didn't return a correct result.

Here's the code that I wrote:

```
var request = require("request");

exports.index = function(req, res) {
    request.get("http://ipinfo.io/" + req.ip + "/json", function(err, response, body) {
        res.write(body);
        res.end()
    });
}

exports.index2 = function(req, res) {
    request.get("http://ipinfo.io/json", function(err, response, body) {
        res.write(body);
        res.end();
    });
}
```

And I conencted those two functions above to each specific route, say, `http://myapp/index1` and `http://myapp/index2`. However, when I tried to access `http://myapp/index1`, the result is something like follows:

```
{
  "ip": "10.xxx.xx.xx", # BTW, is this ip secure information?
  "hostname": "No Hostname",
  "loc": "",
  "bogon": true
}
```

So it doesn't return a correct value.

When I tried to access `http://myapp/index2`, the result is an IP on AWS, since Heroku uses AWS in its background.

So how can I have it return a proper result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing says:

**"X-Forwarded-For: the originating IP address of the client connecting to the Heroku router"**

So use:

```
req.headers['x-forwarded-for']
```

instead of

```
req.ip
```

If you use `req.ip`, you are "asking" ipinfo.io about the IP of the router.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Although the location is not exact, now I've got the correct values.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're behind a proxy, and you're passing an internal IP address to ipinfo.io. You should enable the "trust proxy" setting so that express pulls the correct IP from the `X-Forwarded-For` header, eg:

`app.enable('trust proxy')`

And then you can use req.ip will correctly return the client's IP. You probably shouldn't use `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']` directly because that could contain a list of IPs.

More details are available at http://expressjs.com/guide.html#proxies