# geocoder.ip('me') work locally but not on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, geocoder

I am using Django and need to get the user's current location, so I use `geocoder.ip('me')`. It works fine locally, but after I deploy it on Heroku, it seems like it's not working. Is that because the IP address or something like that? How can I fix it? Or is there any way else that is easier for me to access user current location in *views.py*? Thank you.

I found the way to get the ip address in [How do I get user IP address in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581789/how-do-i-get-user-ip-address-in-django), but I don't know how to really get the ip address so that I can use it in other part of the code.

```
def get_client_ip(self,request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[-1]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip

class RecommendView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'event/recommend.html'
    context_object_name = 'recommend_event_list'
    today = datetime.now().date()
    end = today + timedelta(7)
    time_start = datetime.combine(today, time())
    time_end = datetime.combine(end, time())
    ip = get_client_ip()
    myloc = geocoder.ip(ip,key='my_key')
    def get_queryset(self):
        rec=Event.objects.filter(post_date__range=(self.time_start, self.time_end))
        for event in rec:
            g = geocoder.mapbox(event.address, key='my_key')
            R = 6373.0
            lat1 = math.radians(self.myloc.lat)
            lon1 = math.radians(self.myloc.lng)
            lat2 = math.radians(g.lat)
            lon2 = math.radians(g.lng)

            dlon = lon2 - lon1
            dlat = lat2 - lat1
            a = math.sin(dlat / 2) ** 2 + math.cos(lat1) * math.cos(lat2) * math.sin(dlon / 2) ** 2

            c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
            dis = R * c
            if dis>20:
                rec=rec.exclude(address=event.address)
        return rec.order_by('-post_date')
```

Comment: what do you mean 'not working', can you be more specific with the error you encountered?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670810/how-to-use-ipinfo-io-in-node-js-and-express-and-heroku-application-properly

Comment: I loop through all my object and get rid of the ones that are far away from 'me', the user. Some objects should be print out since they are close to the user. Locally, it has two left, but after I deploy in heroku, none of them left. So I thought it was because of the ip address, but I am not sure if that is the problem.

Comment: @Selcuk Thank you! But I am very new to web coding, I understand what the problem is, but not sure how I should rewrite my code. geocoder.ip('x-forwarded-for') seems not working either.

Comment: `geocoder` documentation clearly states that you should either pass `'me'` or the actual IP address. So you should extract the IP address from the `X-Forwarded-For` header and pass that value to the `.ipinfo()` method.

Comment: @Selcuk it is possible to do so in python? I cannot find python documentation :(

Comment: You can't find the Python documentation for geocoder? It is the first thing you see when you Google for "geocoder python".

Comment: @Selcuk no, i mean extract the IP address from the X-Forwarded-For header in python

Comment: Have you tried searching for "How can I get data from Django Headers"?